# How to loop through particular column names and clear these fields in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: mysql, foreach, pdo, fatal-error

I am trying to execute a PHP/MySQL query to select a set of columns and clear the fields for a particular record:

```
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT column_name
                    FROM information_schema.columns
                    WHERE table_name = 'users'
                    AND column_name like '%_abc'");

$rows = $sth->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows as $row){

    $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users
                          SET $row = NULL
                          WHERE user_id = $user_id");

    $sth->execute();        

}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: 
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error states what is wrong.

Comment: Please, learn what prepared statements are and how they are supposed to be used. What you currently are doing is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$row` is an array. Try

```
foreach ($rows as $id => $value {
   ... SET $value = NULL ...
}
```

You can look at `$row` using:

```
var_dump($row);
```

Answer (score 2):

instead
`"UPDATE users
    SET $row = NULL
    WHERE user_id = $user_id"`

try `"UPDATE users
    SET {$row['column_name']} = NULL
    WHERE user_id = $user_id"`

Answer (score 0):

`$row` is an array. To access a particular field from the selected rows, use `$row['column_name']`